# Why am I getting a 'Permsission denied' error trying to allocate a sub-directory path to a variable

Tags: shell, path, permissions

I'm having trouble doing an asssignment question where I need to keep track of subdirectories and refer to files within them.

I can create a folder through a specific function but, on the next iteration, I need to refer to the previous folder. I want to reference this folder via a variable value rather than writing out long winded paths to the relevant subdirectory, with the following line:

> parentDir=".branch/objects/snapshot_$parentNum"

$parentNum represents the specific directory, in this case it will be snapshot_0, but when i run my script it stops with an error. I've utilised this format with other references in my script without issue but get this error:

> .branch/objects/snapshot_0: Permission denied

I looked at the permissions on the folder (due to the error message) and they are fine, I've even changed the permissions to 777 without change to the error. Clearly, something else is amiss.

I've been looking and can't work out why I'm receiving this error or what might be contributing to it, any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The error is in a line which you didn't show. Direction: Show at least that line.

Comment: The line noted in the error is line 92, that is the first line i've noted above.

Comment: For a POSIX-shell, the line `parentDir=".branch/objects/snapshot_$parentNum"` is a variable assignment; I don't see where permissions can be involved here. You could put a line with `set -x` before that and see what goes on.